# Name for linear function with rational slope

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a special term for a linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with rational slopes? By "slopes" I mean the vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ describing the hyperplane that is the graph of the function, is a rational vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{Q}^{n-1}$, or equivalently that the 1D matrix describing the function has all rational entries.

I'm tempted to call it "linear rational" or "rational linear", but then it could get confused with a rational function such as $\frac{x^2+1}{x-1}$ that is nonlinear.